# How to click the button by searching a word in webpage(not by ID/element name) using Selenium Wrapper excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to search a word in webpage and click the button to download the respective file. I can't use the ID/element name since it may vary time to time. Because when i checked the source code it has been build in a way that

```
London = "Facility_ctl02_chkSelect" 
Chicago = "Facility_ctl03_chkSelect"
```

In case next day if any changes in the order of the report "Facility_ctl02_chkSelect" may be belong to some other name. So I basically want to search the name first and then find the appropriate ID then only it will work. I have to do this for 20 different locations every time.

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: So do you have a list of "**Location**", that you will check? What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Paul, I am new to selenium and haven't done anything so far. Yes i have the list of name to be searched on the web. Is there anything you could help me on this. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with all the elements and their corresponding text, then compare them against your list and only download the right ones:

```
dim arrList() as variant

arrList = driver.getelementsbyid("Facility_ctl0" & "*" & "_chkSelect").getdata

for i = lbound(arrList) to ubound(arrList)
  for j = 1 to 20             'assuming your list of cities is located in A1:A20
    if arrList(i) = cells(j,1) then
        driver.getelementbyid("Facility_ctl0" & "i" & "_chkSelect").click
        exit for
     end if
   next j
next i
```